# Variável indefinida

Tags: php, variáveis

```
<?php 

session_start();
//validação/////// coloquei o "0" acreditando acabar com esse problema, tambem tentei NULL/////////

$startaction="";
$police="";
$tipo ="0";
$Nome= "0";//atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Endereco="0";//atribuição do campo "endereco" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Bairro= "0";//atribuição do campo "bairo" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Cidade="0";//atribuição do campo "cidade" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Uf= "0";//atribuição do campo "uf" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Cep= $_POST['txtCep'];//atribuição do campo "cep" vindo do formulário para variavel0
$Email= "0";//atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Telefone = "0";//atribuição do campo "telefone" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Celular= "0";//atribuição do campo "celular" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Razao= "0";
$Cnpj= "0";
$Fantasia= "0";
$Endereco2= "0";
$Bairro2= "0";
$Cidade2= "0";
$Uf2= "0";
$Cep2= "0";
$Email2= "0";
$Tel2= "0";
$Fax2="0";
$Celular2= "0";
$site= "0";
$login= "0";//atribuição do campo "login" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha= "0";//atribuição do campo "senha" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha2= "0";//atribui





require_once("action.php"); //váriaveis da página de configuração 





 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
$tipo =$_POST['tipo'];
$Nome= $_POST['txtNome'];//atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Endereco= $_POST['txtEndereco'];//atribuição do campo "endereco" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Bairro= $_POST['txtBairro'];//atribuição do campo "bairo" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Cidade= $_POST['txtCidade'];//atribuição do campo "cidade" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Uf= $_POST['txtUf'];//atribuição do campo "uf" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Cep= $_POST['txtCep'];//atribuição do campo "cep" vindo do formulário para variavel0
$Email= $_POST['txtEmail'];//atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Telefone = $_POST['txtTelefone'];//atribuição do campo "telefone" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Celular= $_POST['txtCelular'];//atribuição do campo "celular" vindo do formulário para variavel
$Razao= $_post['txtRazaoSocial'];
$Cnpj= $_post['txtCnpj'];
$Fantasia= $_post['txtNomeFantasia'];
$Endereco2= $_post['txtEndereco2'];
$Bairro2= $_post['txtBairro2'];
$Cidade2= $_post['txtCidade2'];
$Uf2= $_post['txtUf2'];
$Cep2= $post['txtCep2'];
$Email2= $_post['txtEmail2'];
$Tel2= $_post['txtTelefone2'];
$Fax2= $_post['txtFax2'];
$Celular2= $_post['txtCelular2'];
$site= $_post['txtSite'];
$login= $_POST['login'];//atribuição do campo "login" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha= $_POST['senha'];//atribuição do campo "senha" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha2= $_POST['senha2'];//atribuição do campo "sebha2" vindo do formulário para

$time = $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"];
$data=date ('d/m/Y');
$time =time ('H:i:s');
$query1= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login ='$login'"));

if($tipo =='fisica'){
   if($Nome==="0"||$Endereco==="0"|| $Bairro==="0"||$Cidade==="0"||$Uf==="0" || $Cep==="0" ||$Email==="0"||$Telefone==="0"||$login==="0"||$senha==="0"||$senha2==="0"){ 
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('Todos os campos com * são obrigatórios')</script//>

<?php
 }


}else{

    if(filter_var($Email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        if (strlen($senha)<6){
$police="Digite sua senha contendo no minimo seis caracteres!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php

        } 
    else
    { 
    if($senha<>$senha2){
    $police="Insira nos dois campos a mesma senha!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php
    }
    else{


  if($query1 == 1)
  {$police="Esse usuario ja existe!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php
  }
  if($tipo=='juridica'){

      if($Razao==="0"||$Cnpj==="0"||$Fantasia==="0"||$Endereco2==="0"||$Bairro2==="0"||$Cidade2==="0"||$Uf2==="0"||$Cep2==="0"||$Email2==="0"||$senha==="0"||$senha2==="0"||$login==="0"){ 
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('Todos os campos com * são obrigatórios')</script//>

<?php
 }


}else{

    if(filter_var($Email2,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        if (strlen($senha)<6){
$police="Digite sua senha contendo no minimo seis caracteres!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php

        } 
    else
    { 
    if($senha<>$senha2){
    $police="Insira nos dois campos a mesma senha!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php
    }
    else{


  if($query1 == 1)
  {$police="Esse usuario ja existe!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php
 }
 else{



     if ($police==NULL){
$query = "INSERT INTO usuario (tipo,Nome,Endereco,Bairro,Cidade,Uf,Cep,Email,Telefone,Celular,Razao,Cnpj,Fantasia,Endereco2,Bairro2,Cidade2,Uf2,Cep2,Email2,Tel2,Fax2,Celular2,site,login,senha,data,hora)
 VALUES ('$tipo','$Nome','$Endereco','$Bairro','$Cidade','$Uf','$Cep','$Email','$Telefone','$Celular','$Razao','$Cnpj','$Fantasia','$Endereco2','$Bairro2','$Cidade2','$Uf2','$Cep2','$Email2','$Tel2','$Fax2','$Celular2','$site','$login','$senha','$data','$hora')"or die ("1337");
  $insert = mysql_query ($query,$conexao); 



     }
                if($insert){
                    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastramento efetuado!');window.location.href='produtos'</script>";
                }else{
                    $police="Erro ao cadastrar contate o Administrador!";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.exibeErro('$police')</script//>
<?php

                }}}}}}}}


    }}

//echo "<script type="text/javascript">
    // window.parent.exibeErro('Todos os campos com * são obrigatórios')</script//>"

//echo "<script type="text/javascript">
    // window.parent.exibeErro('Todos os campos com * são obrigatórios')</script//>"



echo ("$tipo")
?>
```

Mas ao colocar o codigo dessa forma aparece:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _post in, linha 56 em diante

Ou seja referente ao atributo oposto ao que estou cadastrando...

que esta corretamente conectado levando todas as variáveis do física. (detalhe utilizei a mesma tabela para evitar incomodo no login)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No php nomes de variáveis são case sensive ou seja maiusculas são diferentes de minusculas a variável global `$_POST` e não `$_post` e o detalhe mais importante, todas as requisições por padrão usam o método get, como você está usando um link troque as ocorrências de `$_POST` e `$_post` por `$_GET`

Comment: Amigo mudei para get somente para pegar o link e poder postar e mostrar que os dados estavam sendo enviado do formulario...
Mas obrigado amigo, voce me ajudou muito, se precisar estarei aqui...

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples, é só um erro de digitação, escreve `_POST` ao invés de `_post` e será resolvido. Maiúsculo e minúsculo faz diferença no nome das variáveis.

O resto é pura invenção. Programar não é chutar soluções, é entender o funcionamento das coisas e fazer o certo.

Comment: KKK Amigo é que estou com pressa e por isso não consegui analisar direito o problema e vi como solução rapida pedir ajuda...

Obrigado amigo, nossa voce me ajudou muito...

Comment: @ElizandroSchmidt pressa é inimiga da perfeição...

Comment: @ElizandroSchmidt no desespero ou na pressa, não vai ajudar nada em resolver os erros. Tenha calma e analise com cuidado seu código, assim você não vai precisar que ninguém analise para você. Mesmo que o prazo esteja estourando, tente manter a calma ;)

Comment: Obrigado amigo ...  mas, não estava conseguindo manter a concentração tambem por estar com a família reunida, desesperado ...
Bom mas, agora estou tendo o cuidado para revisar todos os dados...